# How to access an array element that was added to another array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

my code looks like this

```
planets[0]= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
planettexts[0]= new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial );
planets[0].add(planettexts[0]);
```

now I want to make the **planettext** invisible, but every time I try

```
planets[0].planettexts.visible=false;
```

or

```
planets[0].planettexts[0].visible=false;
```

I get an undefined error. I never had this problem when modifying an element that was not an array and **planettexts** is shown to be a child of **planets[0]**. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use [.add()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.add) you are adding your planettexts[0] object to the children Array property of the planets[0] object.

You would therefore need to access it via the [.children](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.children) property. Something like:

```
planets[0].children[0].visible=false;
```

(Though you would need to check which Array position is the correct child! In the above code you only have one child, so children[0] should be correct)